# ExactTarget - Send email to group via Fuel SDK?

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk

Can an email be sent to a Group via the Fuel SDK?  If not, how can it be done with another API or SDK?

Comment: test the sample in this url: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/107419/reviewed-why-i-see-the-count-of-completed-queued-errored-on-triggered-sends-to

Answer (score 1):

The way I am sending email using FuelSDK php, I have created DataExtension then using this (search for SendEmailToDataExtension sample code)

```
$response = $myclient->SendEmailToDataExtension($EmailIDForSendDefinition, $SendableDataExtensionCustomerKey,$SendClassificationCustomerKey);
```

Where 
$EmailIDForSendDefinition: is your email ID which you can get by getting email properties.
$SendableDataExtensionCustomerKey: is you DataExtension Key again you can get this by looking into properties of Data Extension.

$SendClassificationCustomerKey: This is you Send Classification e:g DefaultTransactional

To send email to List have same procedure and function used for this in fuelsdk is "SendEmailToList".

Using one of these code, instead of listid/DataExtension id provide group Id and and send email.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the PHP version of the SDK, check out the example for sending to a List at:
https://github.com/ExactTarget/FuelSDK-Ruby/blob/master/samples/sample-email.senddefinition.rb

A group is basically just a special type of List, it has an ID which can be used interchangeably with a standard List ID.

Comment: That looks like a link to the Ruby SDK.

Comment: Thanks Mac, that's great to know.  How do you find the ID for the group though?  With no access to the Groups via the SDK, it still feels like a dead-end.

Comment: By the way, I did try getting all Lists, but my group wasn't included in them.

Comment: I also tried using an ID I found via the web interface, but the get() against ET_List() failed to return anything but an empty stub object.